# marging right extending width of the page? how to disable it

Tags: html, css

i am facing a problem in positioning, when i move element to the left its creating blank space in right, a yellow unwanted margin-right is forming , what is the solution?

[image]

css

```
.product_4{
   width: 40vw;
   position: relative;
   left: 52vw;
   bottom: 24vw;

   }
```

html

```
<div className="product_4">
                <StorefrontIcon id="product_4_img"/>
                <h1 className="product_4_text">ViewInventory</h1>
                <p id="product_4_p">Canola, flax seeds, peas and lentils are widely produced and exported grains in Canada...</p>
                <Link to="/" id="product_4_btn">Explore More</Link>
            </div>
```

how to avoid the yellow margin-right

Comment: Can you also type the the our_product class css?

Answer (score 0):

According to the dev tools that element doesn't have any margin. That's probably collapsed margin from some parent element(`<body>`, `#root`, `div.our_products` or any other unnamed container `<div>`s).

Inspect them and remove it or add `overflow: hidden` on `<body>` if you want to remove the scroll